# How to run an emulator that looks like android studio emulator in visual studio code?

Tags: android, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I want to have an emulator that has the android frame just like the android studio emulator has without having to install the android studio.

Here is how the vscode emulator looks like

[image: vscode emulator]

and here is how the android studio emulator looks like

[image: android studio emulator]

I'm currently developing mobile development modules and I think the emulator with android frame would look nicer. Thanks guys, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the android ios extension in vscode. This extension doesn't come with a device frame or skin. Try using genny motion emulator. First download the emulator from here

```
https://www.genymotion.com/download/
```

It seems more viable than the extension and it is lighter to download compared to android studio